Excel formula gives different result than manual calculation
I have a more or less complex formula in my sheet to calculate the remaining amounts of an asset after a transaction happened. As of right now, unfortunately, instead of showing 0 after selling all of this asset, it shows -3.63798E-12
When I run through the formula, I can see the sum of all amounts ever bought is exactly the same as the sum of all the amounts ever sold. See here.

If I go a step further however, the result of this calculation is this.

If I take all the same values and calculate them "manually" it equals 0 perfectly. See here.

Does anybody know what is going on here?
Thanks!

I suspect the values you show are the results of calculations, and not the actual values. That being the case, you should read Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel for the explanation.

All machines have a finite number of places for calculation and for display. This causes rounding errors.
A simple example: (1 / 3) x 3 logically equals exactly 1, but as a decimal calculation, 1 / 3 = 0.333... or 0.3̅, and if you tried manually multiplying 0.333... x 3, the result is 0.99999999999... to as many decimal places as you care to go. That "paradox" is given as proof that 1.0̅  = 0.9̅ , but you have to make your spreadsheet show the answer as desired, or 1, for this problem.
The result you got, -3.63798E-12 in engineering notation, can be written as -3.63798 x 10-12 or as 0.00000000000363798. That is a very small number compared to the number one; it can be said to approach zero, for the purpose of your spreadsheet. In your calculation, it can be rounded to zero.
You can handle this issue a few ways:

When displaying numbers, use a decimal number format with a limited number of decimal places. For financial transactions, two decimal places might be enough.
In calculation, use the ROUND() function to round results to the required number of decimal places.
Set the precision of calculations on the spreadsheet.


Alright, I see. Thanks for your help. I really want to make it work without rounding. The problem is that yes, for the values I have now, they only go until 8 digits after the decimal point but there might be values in the future that need even more precision.
So for now I solved it by adding a "IF(Amount < 0.000000000009;0;Amount)" into my formula. I used LET() to assign my long formula to the variable "Amount" and then check it in the end. So far, it seems to work, so I'll stick with it. I think it should be fine. Thanks again and all the best!
